# bad page map bug during snapshot

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, kernel, snapshot, udevd

I ran the following command to create a snapshot volume. But the kernel received a bug and the kvm hypervisor stopped responding. Why is the error and how to fix it?

```
lvcreate -L20G -s -n volume_A_backup /dev/vgroup/volumeA
```

Error Log:

```
Mar 10 02:36:59 kvm kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process udevd  pte:800000081ad43645 pmd:409f37067
Mar 10 02:36:59 kvm kernel: addr:00006aff4f837000 vm_flags:00100173 anon_vma:ffff88081f7dc448 mapping:(null) index:7fffffff1
Mar 10 02:37:02 kvm kernel: Pid: 5091, comm: udevd Not tainted 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113ef18>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d8/0x290
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8111b970>] ? generic_file_aio_read+0x380/0x700
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113f03b>] ? vm_normal_page+0x6b/0x70
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8114179f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x61f/0xc30
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811476d7>] ? exit_mmap+0x87/0x170
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8106b50c>] ? mmput+0x6c/0x120
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811889a4>] ? flush_old_exec+0x484/0x690
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811d9700>] ? load_elf_binary+0x350/0x1ab0
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113f3ff>] ? follow_page+0x31f/0x470
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811446e0>] ? __get_user_pages+0x110/0x430
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811d7abe>] ? load_misc_binary+0x9e/0x3f0
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81144a99>] ? get_user_pages+0x49/0x50
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81189fa7>] ? search_binary_handler+0x137/0x370
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8118a4f7>] ? do_execve+0x217/0x2c0
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff810095ea>] ? sys_execve+0x4a/0x80
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8100b4ca>] ? stub_execve+0x6a/0xc0
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process dmsetup  pte:00000700 pmd:409f34067
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: addr:00006a3dcd3df000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:(null) mapping:ffff88081b8385e0 index:27
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: vma->vm_ops->fault: filemap_fault+0x0/0x500
Mar 10 02:37:03 kvm kernel: vma->vm_file->f_op->mmap: ext4_file_mmap+0x0/0x60 [ext4]
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: Pid: 5091, comm: dmsetup Tainted: G    B      ---------------    2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113ef18>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d8/0x290
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113f03b>] ? vm_normal_page+0x6b/0x70
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8114179f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x61f/0xc30
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811476d7>] ? exit_mmap+0x87/0x170
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8106b50c>] ? mmput+0x6c/0x120
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8107312b>] ? exit_mm+0x12b/0x180
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff810734df>] ? do_exit+0x15f/0x870
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073c48>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073cd7>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process dmsetup  pte:00000f00 pmd:409f34067
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: addr:00006a3dcd3ef000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:(null) mapping:ffff88081b8385e0 index:37
Mar 10 02:37:04 kvm kernel: vma->vm_ops->fault: filemap_fault+0x0/0x500
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: vma->vm_file->f_op->mmap: ext4_file_mmap+0x0/0x60 [ext4]
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: Pid: 5091, comm: dmsetup Tainted: G    B      ---------------    2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113ef18>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d8/0x290
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113f03b>] ? vm_normal_page+0x6b/0x70
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8114179f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x61f/0xc30
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811476d7>] ? exit_mmap+0x87/0x170
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8106b50c>] ? mmput+0x6c/0x120
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8107312b>] ? exit_mm+0x12b/0x180
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff810734df>] ? do_exit+0x15f/0x870
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073c48>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073cd7>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process dmsetup  pte:00000f00 pmd:409f35067
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: addr:00006a3dcd447000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:(null) mapping:ffff88081b8385e0 index:8f
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: vma->vm_ops->fault: filemap_fault+0x0/0x500
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: vma->vm_file->f_op->mmap: ext4_file_mmap+0x0/0x60 [ext4]
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: Pid: 5091, comm: dmsetup Tainted: G    B      ---------------    2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113ef18>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d8/0x290
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8112f42e>] ? __put_single_page+0x1e/0x30
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8113f03b>] ? vm_normal_page+0x6b/0x70
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8114179f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x61f/0xc30
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff811476d7>] ? exit_mmap+0x87/0x170
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8106b50c>] ? mmput+0x6c/0x120
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8107312b>] ? exit_mm+0x12b/0x180
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff810734df>] ? do_exit+0x15f/0x870
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073c48>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff81073cd7>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Mar 10 02:37:05 kvm kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process dmsetup  pte:00000300 pmd:409f35067
```

Answer (score 3):

Your kernel is tainted:

```
Tainted: G    B
```

`B` there means[1]:

> A process has been found in a Bad page state, indicating a corruption of the virtual memory subsystem, possibly caused by malfunctioning RAM or cache memory.

Basically most `BUG: Bad page map in process` are related to physical memory failure. But in presence of virtualization it may also be a hypervizor bug.
But I would suggest you first check `mcelog(8)`.

[1] http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3582750